# create flexible frame for a photo?

Tags: ios, uiimage

i want to create a frame for a photo.
(i have many different frame and many photos).

there are two frame images.

*i.stack.imgur.com/KC0Pm.png*

the source pic is something like the above and i want to change it to:

*i.stack.imgur.com/t8CwQ.png*

i upload my code below,and it still has problems.
the result is like 
*i.stack.imgur.com/jO0O5.png*

**CODE HERE**
http://www.box.net/shared/cmtz0e48a5urtajxu4yn

can someone help to solve it??

Answer (score 0):

Update your "-imageWithImage:covertToSize:" using 
"-stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:" method of UIImage.
It should work fine.

[UIImage Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth%3atopCapHeight%3a)

Comment: stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:  only repeat 1px,but here i want to repeat part of the frame.so,it didn't work